# cropper.jscant initialize blob image <img>tag by blueimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp, cropper

So what i want :

select an image with input type file,
downscale with [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image),
crop that image with [cropper.js](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

so the blueimp part is working fine, the image gets resized to maxWidth property and is appended as `<img>` tag to "#imagearea" then i want to initialize cropper.js based on that  tag, like in the docs, heres my code

```
  document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = function (e) {
      var loadingImage = loadImage(
          e.target.files[0],
          function (img) {


            $(img).attr("style","max-width: 100%;")
            $('#imagearea').append(img)
            // now i see the image and when i inspect dom its a <img> tag

            // so lets initialize the cropper
            $('#imagearea').find("img").cropper({
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              crop: function(e) {

              }
            });
          },
          {maxWidth: 1280}
      );

  };
```

but when initializing the cropper, 
first i get an 404 error like

```
GET blob:http://foo.bar/64c77709-29f7-44ba-8772-49517e7976e5 404 (Not Found)
```

and then

Uncaught RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
    at DataView.getUint8 ()
    at m (6eaf333.js:7051)
    at e.value (6eaf333.js:7051)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.onload (6eaf333.js:7051)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use "noRevoke " option.

```js
document.getElementById('file-input').onchange = function (e) {
      var loadingImage = loadImage(
          e.target.files[0],
          function (img) {


            $(img).attr("style","max-width: 100%;")
            $('#imagearea').append(img)
            // now i see the image and when i inspect dom its a <img> tag

            // so lets initialize the cropper
            $('#imagearea').find("img").cropper({
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              crop: function(e) {

              }
            });
          },
          {maxWidth: 1280,noRevoke: true}
      );

  };
```